# A generic IEnumerator to enumerate COM collections

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, rubberduck, com

As I wrapped the VBIDE API, I encountered a number of "collection types" (`Windows`, `CodePanes`, `VBComponents`, `VBProjects`, `References`, etc.) - these types implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, so if I wanted to be able to iterate my wrappers like this for example:

> ```
> using (var projects = _vbe.VBProjects)
> {
>     foreach (var project in projects.Where(p => p.Protection == ProjectProtection.Unprotected))
>     {
>         yield return project.Name;
>     }
> }
> ```

...then I was going to be needing some custom `IEnumerator` implementation, because even if I could explicitly `.Cast<Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers.Project>()` every time, at runtime the cast would fail because the enumerator yields a COM object, not a wrapper type.

So I made a generic `ComWrapperEnumerator<TComCollection, TWrapperItem>`, where `TComCollection` is the collection type (must implement `IEnumerable`) and `TWrapperItem` is the type of the `SafeComWrapper<T>` to be created and returned - am I doing this right? I don't like the way I'm assuming the constructor only has a single `T` parameter (where `T` is the COM type being wrapped by `TWrapperItem`), is there a better way?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers
{
    public class ComWrapperEnumerator<TComCollection, TWrapperItem> : IEnumerator<TWrapperItem>
        where TComCollection : IEnumerable
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator _internal;

        public ComWrapperEnumerator(TComCollection items)
        {
            _internal = items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var disposable = _internal as IDisposable;
            if (disposable == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            disposable.Dispose();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _internal.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _internal.Reset();
        }

        public TWrapperItem Current
        {
            get { return (TWrapperItem)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TWrapperItem), _internal.Current); }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }
}
```

Anything else?

For context, here's the `SafeComWrapper<T>` abstract base class' constructor:

> ```
> protected SafeComWrapper(T comObject)
> {
>     _comObject = comObject;
> }
> ```

Here's how the enumerator is used, here in the `CodePanes` wrapper:

```
IEnumerator<CodePane> IEnumerable<CodePane>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new ComWrapperEnumerator<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CodePanes, CodePane>(ComObject);
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new ComWrapperEnumerator<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CodePanes, CodePane>(ComObject);
}
```

I can't think of a clean way to get generic type parameters inferred by the compiler, so every `new ComWrapperEnumerator` needs these ugly generic type parameters.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading about issues with `IEnumerator` not being disposable. Not sure if that was true or relevant.

Comment: you must have been quite sleepy to write this code ;)

Comment: @BrunoCosta clearly this coffee needs more mug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ComWrapperEnumerator` is generic in two types without needing to.
You don't really care about `TComCollection` aside that it must be an `IEnumerable`, 
thus that generic type can disappear from your class and you will end up with a constructor method that receives an `IEnumerable`.

```
public ComWrapperEnumerator(IEnumerable items)
{
    _internal = items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Normally the non generic version calls the generic version of the method, removing your code repetition:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    //call the generic GetEnumerator
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

In this particular case I think there isn't any other way to improve the instantion of `ComWrapperEnumerator`.
However one way that normally is used to avoid specifying types on constructors is to specify a static method to instantiate the type.
If you look for example to `Tuple.Create` this is exactly what they do.

The hack could work with code like this:

```
public static ComWrapperEnumerator<T> Create<T>(T t, IEnumerable value){
    return new ComWrapperEnumerator<T>(value);
}

//usage
ComWrapperEnumerator.Create(default(CodePane), ComObject);
```

You can always provide methods for all types that you care about:

```
public static ComWrapperEnumerator<CodePane> CreateCodePane(IEnumerable value){
    return new ComWrapperEnumerator<CodePane>(value);
}
```

But anyway, now that you have one less generic type maybe you are no longer concerned about that.

> I don't like the way I'm assuming the constructor only has a single T
>   parameter (where T is the COM type being wrapped by TWrapperItem), is
>   there a better way?

Yes there is. Not only there is but would also remove the need of that pesky `Activator.CreateInstace`. The most straightforward approach that I can think of is to pass a Func that would receive the COM object and return an instance of the type you want. This would be a parameter of the constructor.

```
private readonly Func<object, TWrapperItem> _createItem;
public ComWrapperEnumerator(IEnumerable items, Func<object, TWrapperItem> createItem)
{
    _internal = items.GetEnumerator();
    _createItem = createItem;
}

public TWrapperItem Current
{
    get { return _createItem(_internal.Current); }
}

object IEnumerator.Current
{
    get { return Current; }
}
```

Obviously you can always fallback to `Activator`:

```
private TWrapperItem CreateItem(object value){
   return (TWrapperItem )Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TWrapperItem), value);
}

public ComWrapperEnumerator(IEnumerable items, Func<object, TWrapperItem> createItem = null)
{
    _internal = items.GetEnumerator();
    _createItem = createItem ?? CreateItem;
}
```

Note that if you go with this approach you may consider to come back to having two generic types on your class, so you could have a typesafe `_createItem`.

Comment: `return GetEnumerator()` won't compile, because the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces are explicitly implemented, so either I make `IEnumerator<CodePane> IEnumerable<CodePane>.GetEnumerator()` a public member, or I cast `this` to `IEnumerable<CodePane>` in the non-generic `GetEnumerator` method. I think I prefer making the generic method an instance member, what do you think?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think I would rather cast it. Making it an instance member expose details that you might not want to.

Answer (score 3):

You rarely need to manually implement enumerators. In your case, you should probably just go with extension methods. For example:

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TTarget> Wrap<TTarget>(this IEnumerable source, Func<object, TTarget> converter)
    {
        return source.Cast<object>().Select(converter);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TTarget> Wrap<TTarget>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        return source.Wrap(x => (TTarget)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (TTarget), x));
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't think there is a pretty way to dynamically convert one generic type to another. So using `Activator` is not a bad solution, especially since you can not modify source types. That being said, there are libraries, that do dynamic conversion using explicit cast operators (that you can define on your wrapper classes). I have no idea how on earth they do it (a lot of reflection involved?), but you can give them a try. Here is an example of [such library](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding), that I've used in the past.

Comment: @BrunoCosta, haha, you are right! Silly me :)

Comment: And I should say that I must have been quite sleepy to write my review. Just go with this approach, much simpler.

Comment: The problem is that the code base is already written, I just barely got the test project to build after swapping all VBIDE API references everywhere in Rubberduck so it's using the wrappers now - and without the enumerator I'll get invalid cast exceptions at runtime wherever I forget to use the extension method; I like this solution, but I think this is one such case where an enumerator makes sense.